# Node.js with Npm standard installation vs global installation of Npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed `node.js v8.11.3` from their website, and it comes with `npm v5.6` built-in.

Those files are in my "program files\nodejs" folder.

But recently I got aware that I can run:

`npm install -g npm @"some version (upgrade or downgrade)"`

and another version will be installed globally and those files will by in my "%appdata%\npm\node_modules\" folder.

Question1:

**If I do this, what happens when I run the next npm command on VSCode Terminal? Which version would I be using then? Will the global version override the buil-in version?**

Question 2:

***And also, what happens if I install npm locally in one of my projects? Does the local version alsos override the built-in version? Does it override any global version as well?***

Question 3:

***It feels weird to use `npm` to install `npm`. Is this common?***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1: If I do this, what happens when I run the next npm command on VSCode Terminal? Which version would I be using then? Will the global version override the built-in version?**

When you install software on Windows and attempt to use a command from the console, it takes the name of the command you're running and looks in your Windows' **PATH Environment Variable** for the list of folders to look for when you run a command. If you were to run `npm install -g npm` like you said, the version of NPM you ran when it came to your terminal would be the first version that appears in your PATH Environment Variable.

**Question 2: And also, what happens if I install npm locally in one of my projects? Does the local version also override the built-in version? Does it override any global version as well?**

Since your PATH Environment Variable likely doesn't extend to the `node_modules` folder in your project, it likely wouldn't change anything. Locally installed node modules are local in nature, meaning they rarely interact with anything outside of their folder, they have to be called.

**Question 3: It feels weird to use npm to install npm. Is this common?**

I can't say it is common. I doubt most node developers install npm on its own very often. And if they do, they likely don't do it through an already working npm. However, you can *update* all of your installed packages through npm, including npm itself, using `npm update`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically according to the doc i would have one answer for the two questions :

> If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of your project.
>   If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

the doc [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)